# htaccess remove trailing slash causes redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, trailing-slash

I am amending my htaccess file to achieve non-www to www (this is working) plus removing the trailing slash at the end of the URL, e.g.:

```
www.domain.bc.ca/club/ ---> www.domain.bc.ca/club
www.domain.bc.ca/club/index.html/  ---> www.domain.bc.ca/club/index.html
```

The portion of the htaccess file is below - the Force www bit is working; the Remove trailing slash bit is not.  Help!  Many thanks, Amanda.

```
# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.bc\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#
# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you're trying to access a directory when this happens. In your example, the "club" seems to be a directory and when you redirect `/club/` to `/club`, a module called mod_dir will redirect it back to having the trailing slash again. There's a really good reason for this, because if the trailing slash is missing for a directory, the directory's **contents will be displayed** instead of the index file. That means if you were able to go to `www.domain.com/club` (without the trailing slash), you'd see all the contents of the `club` directory instead of the `club/index.html` file.

If that's ok with you, then you can turn off mod_dir by adding this to your htaccess file:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

But then you'd need to internally *add the slash back in*:

```
DirectorySlash Off

# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.bc\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#
# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Add the slash back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [L]
```